# Comment interpréter l'expression «réduite à l'os»?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

Comment interpréter l'expression «réduite à l'os»? Je l'ai trouvée dans la phrase «(...)mais leur liberté de culte est réduite à l’os». (Voici [le texte](http://fr.aleteia.org/2016/12/21/quand-le-nom-de-jesus-christ-designe-une-torture-inhumaine/?utm_campaign=NL_fr&utm_source=daily_newsletter&utm_medium=mail&utm_content=NL_fr))

Est-ce que c'est une expression idiomatique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le verbe [réduire à beaucoup de variantes mais elles indiquent toujours une contrainte forte, une transformation forcée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9duit).

L'expression **réduire à l'os** est une métaphore d'un membre ou d'un bout de viande auquel on aurait enlevé tous les muscles, les nerfs et la vie, et où il ne resterait plus que l'os. Un membre qui existerait encore, mais qui aurait été réduit à presque rien sous la contrainte.

J'interpréterai donc cette phrase comme signifiant que la liberté de culte a été progressivement diminué jusqu'à devenir uniquement symbolique.

Comment: Merci pour votre aide ;)

Answer (score 2):

Oui, c'est idiomatique, et ça veut dire "réduit au minimum vital".

Comment: Merci pour votre aide ;)

Answer (score 0):

Curieusement, « reduire à l'os » pourrait presque être positif : si on enlève le superflu, il ne reste que l'os !

Mais je ne crois pas que cette interprétation, un peu trop subtile, soit la bonne ici :-)